# How to set custom column header to a datagridview and display datatable records?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

QI want to display queried records from SQl Server which are in a table with custom column headers. How can I do it ?

My querying function is as below

```
        private DataTable GetRecords(int QID, DateTime FromDate, DateTime ToDate)
    {
        SqlConnection myConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CONNSTRING"].ConnectionString);

        // Create the command and set its properties.
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = myConn;
        command.CommandText = "sp_GetRecords";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // Add the input parameter and set its properties.
        SqlParameter parameter1 = new SqlParameter();
        parameter1.ParameterName = "@QID";
        parameter1.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int; 
        parameter1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameter1.Value = QID;

        SqlParameter parameter2 = new SqlParameter();
        parameter2.ParameterName = "@FromDate";
        parameter2.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime;
        parameter2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameter2.Value = FromDate;

        SqlParameter parameter3 = new SqlParameter();
        parameter3.ParameterName = "@ToDate";
        parameter3.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime;
        parameter3.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameter3.Value = ToDate;
        // Add the parameter to the Parameters collection. 
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter1);
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter2);
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter3);
         myConn.Open();
         SqlDataReader GetAgentTransactions = command.ExecuteReader();
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
         dt.Load(GetAgentTransactions);             
         GetAgentTransactions.Close();
         myConn.Close();
         return dt;

    }
```

To bind and display in datagridview, I have the following on a display button click event.

```
 protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       DataTable table = new DataTable();
       table = GetRecords(1, Convert.ToDateTime(txtFromDate.Text.Trim()), Convert.ToDateTime(txtToDate.Text.Trim()));
       datagridview.DataSource = table;
       datagridview.DataBind();           
    }
       }
```

I want the returned records to be shown under the column headers as Sl. No, Name and Reg. Number. How can I do it ? Please help with a code example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you can't change the SQL queries to get column names the way you want. So let's modify the DataGridView.

If you see the column names from the DataTable as it is in the DataGridView as columns it is because it auto-generates them.

If you want your own header text in columns you have to specify them yourself.

1st you need to turn off column auto-generation. For that set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false` in the DataGridView.

Then you have to add columns manually and specify `DataField` values in each column equal to the real column name from SQL Server and `HeaderText` equal to your desired display name of the column.

Now when you bind the `DataTable` it will generate columns for the matching columns in the `DataGridView` according to the `DataField` and `HeaderText` values.

Checkout the Example here for sample markup: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.columns.aspx

EDIT:

Here's a sample GridView markup to show how you have to manually setup columns.

1. Note that `AutoGenerateColumns` is set to `false`
2. `DataField` should be the field name in the database. `HeaderText` should be your text.

   ```
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
       <Columns>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="DOB" HeaderText="Date Of Birth" />
       </Columns>

   </asp:GridView>
   ```

Comment: Yes, if I bind directly the datagridview will directly set the column headers as per the data table which i don't to happen. I want to display the columns with my own headers. can anyone post the altered code for the same ?

Comment: Guganeshan: Thanks for your reply.
I tried your suggestion, I just get a blank patch on the grid area but not headers/columns/rows are displayed. Just a blank white space. Sad it did not work. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @Codebug - I have edited my answer to show sample GridView markup. You can put your own DataField names and HeaderText. Hope that helps

Comment: @Guganeshan- I used the code above and it worked! Earlier I had created these columns in design mode but it never gave me the expected display. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this on windows forms:

```
            1. dgr_donors.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            2. dgr_donors.Columns.Add("id", "id");
            3. dgr_donors.Columns.Add("BCode", "BarCode");
```